# Ammeter (DSN-VC288) showing wrong values

Tags: led, current, multimeter, led-strip, led-driver

I am building my own RGB-LED-Strip (WS1812B) controller, including an Ammeter bought at my local electronics store to monitor the current consumed by the LEDs. On the back it can be identified as a "DSN-VC288".

I've looked up the wiring and stumbled upon this:

https://www.electroson.com/documentos/D_MD9059_0_MD9059%20DISPLAY%20LED_DOCUMENTACI%C3%93N.pdf

[image]

I am piggybacking of the power-supply for the LEDs so the left side applies. I've adapted that design to this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPDj0b.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now here comes the problem: The Ammeter is showing 20 Milliamps for 15 LEDs cycling through the rainbow at half brightness. That is not realistic. Proof:

[image]

I guess it is somehow only showing the current passing through the first LED, which is plausible because these LEDs are supposed to need around 20 Milliamps individually in my configuration.

How can I wire this meter to show the current consumed by the whole array?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If the 15 leds are full white 100% brightness does it read what you expect?

Comment: Just test the meter with some resistors as the load and use I = V/R. That should give you a good idea of whether it's working / accurate.

Comment: @Passerby Good idea, just tested it out, it's reading 290 Milliamps for the 15 LEDs white at full brightness. Considering that that should in theory consume around 60 Milliamps for each (source: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-neopixel-uberguide/powering-neopixels) it seems like the meter is reading more than the first LED, but that still seems to low for me (divided by 15 that's around 20 Millamps per LED).

Comment: If you're using a *swcthing* ("digital") power supply, it's output is **not** pure DC, but pulsed. Without specs for the meter, it's hard to know if it's detecting *peak* current, or trying to *average* the pulse waveform and getting it wrong. Use a linear power supply to measure the output with that meter, or somehow *smooth* the measurements, e.g. with a large capacitor across the resistor.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I'm using this one: https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B01HRR9GY4. I believe it is non-switching.

Comment: http://www.mantech.co.za/datasheets/products/DSN-VC288.pdf

Comment: @BruceAbbott That is exactly how I connected it. I don't need an external shunt, my theoretical maximum current will be 4 Amps. What do you want to tell me?

Comment: The official manual includes error specs. Assuming they are accurate then either your meter is out of spec or the LEDs really are only drawing ~20mA. It's possible the meter has a zero offset that makes low readings look even lower. Do you have a multimeter to compare it to, or can you test it with a resistor that should draw ~20mA?

Comment: @BruceAbbott I just tested it out with a 10Ohm resistor. Just before the resistor started smoking it was reading 280Milliamps. It should be just about double that. (By Ohm's law with a voltage around 5.5Volts)